# Dynamically assign attribute value to custom vf component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a custom vf component that takes in account ID as a parameter. The vf component takes in the ID of the account and displays all the contacts under it. I have a pageblocktable that iterates over a list of accounts. How do I pass the corresponding account ID to the component whenever a click is made on the corresponding account name in the table. Also how can I rerender the component part? Thanks in advance

```
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccList}" var="Acc">
        <apex:column value="{!Acc.Name}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<c:DisplayContacts AccID="" id="DispConComp"/>
```

Comment: If you want that it should reflect new value then you need to reRender it. I would suggest update a controller side field with selected account type when selected via actionSupport and then use that as a parameter in component and then reRender the component. You would results you are looking for.